# Can someone give me some scenarios why we need to register BroadcastReceiver dynamically?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

As title, I am wondering under what situation we must register the BroadcastReceiver dynamically in an Activity? Can somebody give me some scenarios the statically registered receivers cannot fulfill?

Thanks:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can somebody give me some scenarios the statically registered receivers cannot fulfill?

In addition to @Pedro Loureiro's scenario, certain system broadcasts (e.g., `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED`, `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF`, `ACTION_SCREEN_ON`) can only be received by dynamically-registered broadcast receivers.

Also, there will be patterns where you will register dynamically for a broadcast to be sent from your own service, such as the activity-or-`Notification` scenario I outline in [this blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/08/11/activity-notification-ordered-broadcast.html).

Answer (score 0):

For example, you may have an application and in the preferences there might be an option to notify the user about certain events. When this option is on, you would register the corresponding broadcast receiver.